Inconsistent format of UTF-8 characters in C++
I've been trying to develop a small console app in C++ for Windows that interacts with an SQLite database. However, this Database may contain UTF-8 characters, e.g. Greek letters. Therefore it is necessary for the program to input these characters from the user console, use them in queries and output them.
I'd like to input these characters using getline or ideally getch.
At first not even simply inputing and outputing a utf-8 string worked.
Using
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);

Caused the input strings to have the correct length, but all the characters where null. E.g. inputting "ΑΒΓ" would store a string of 3 characters of value 0.
Using 1253 (The code page for Greek) instead of CP_UTF8 worked for concatenating, inputting and outputing. I noticed in the debugger that the values of the strings were invalid and wouldn't show up correctly. I also noticed that instead of 2 bytes per character there was only 1, but since it would output fine I didn't think much of it, as there can't have been loss of data.
However, the SQLite API didn't agree. Constructing the query using the user input would give no result. Executing a query using a hardcoded string literal with the same utf-8 character would give a result, but both the hardcoded query and the results had a different format than the user input I got before. They would render correctly in the debugger, had 2 bytes per character, and would output giberish under the 1253 CP but correctly under CP_UTF8.
I have not found any reference to this discrepancy online, though I'm not sure If I even looked in the right places. Since the SQLite results output correctly under CP_UTF8, I'd like at the very least to be able to input characters in the SQLite API desired format (i.e. the same format that literals are stored), or at least be able to convert from the current 1253 format to it.
Below is a minimal reproducible example with the concepts I mentioned above:
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);

    //Dysfunctional Input
    string input1;
    cout << "Enter greek letters: ";
    cin >> input1;
    cout << "You entered: " << input1 << endl; //input1 has correct size but all chars are null

    SetConsoleOutputCP(1253);
    SetConsoleCP(1253);

    //Working Input and Output
    string input2;
    cout << "Enter greek letters: ";
    cin >> input2;
    cout << "You entered: " << input2 << endl; //Should output properly
    
    //Printing a literal
    string literall = u8"Γειά σας";
    cout << "Literal under 1253: " << literall << endl; //Giberish

    //Printing a literal under CP_UTF8
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    cout << "Literal under CP_UTF8: " << literall << endl; //Correct output

    return 0;
}

The above code shows similar results with getline and _getch instead of cin which is promising.
Final Notes:

Terminal doesn't seem to be the issue, since I am able to input and output greek letters when the correct ConsoleCP is set.
setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); seems to also cause the working examples from above to fail. Input "ΑΒΓ" becomes "ΑΑΑ" and both literals are giberish.


The whole point of encoding is to make the same bytes represent completely different characters.  Trying to output UTF-8 using 1253 encoding will result in gibberish almost by definition.

Are you sure your SQLite is configured to use UTF-8?

And 2 bytes per character implies UTF-16 instead of UTF-8.

@MarkRansom the database contained records with data in greek, and hardcoding queries in my console app does give a correct result as mentioned above. I assume this means it is configured to use UTF-8?

The literal defined in the example above is 8 letters long, but shows up as size 15 in the debugger. Does this mean it's being stored in UTF-16? The C-SQLite API only supports UTF-8 but its results have 2 bytes per greek character so I'm not sure how to make sense of this.

Are you compiling with the /utf-8 compiler flag?

@Eljay I just added it and it doesn't seem to make a difference. Does it have any impact on the console character sets?

@andydexter the /utf-8 flag has no effect on the console at all, only on the character set that the compiler uses to parse your source code, and to store narrow string literals in the executable. In this case, you are better off NOT trying to finesse the console to use UTF-8. Use std::wcin and std::wstring instead to work with UTF-16 strings (since Windows is a native UTF-16 OS), and convert the data to UTF-8 when passing it to the SQLite API, using std::wstring_convert or WideCharToMultiByte() or ICONV/ICU or any other equivalent Unicode-handling API/library of your choosing.

OK, 15 bytes not 16.  That is not "two bytes per character".  It almost is, because except for the blank those Greek characters become two bytes each in UTF-8 but that's just a coincidence.  Specifically it's "\xce\x93\xce\xb5\xce\xb9\xce\xac \xcf\x83\xce\xb1\xcf\x82".  UTF-8 can be from 1 to 4 bytes per character, depending on the character.

UTF-8 and the Windows Console
I have never been able to make the Windows Console work directly with UTF-8 without kludging something, either because of Windows itself or the compiler/version/libc/etc.
However, using the Console API with wide-character functions always works. So to make UTF-8 I/O work, you need to imbue the standard streams with converting filters appropriately. The following sets things up:
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Shell32")

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
namespace duthomhas::utf8::console
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
{

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Input: public std::streambuf
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  using int_type = std::streambuf::int_type;
  using traits   = std::streambuf::traits_type;

  HANDLE  handle;
  char    buffer[ 4 ];
  wchar_t c;
  DWORD   n;

  Input( HANDLE handle ): handle(handle) { }
  Input( const Input& that ): handle(that.handle) { }

  virtual int_type underflow() override
  {
    auto ok = ReadConsoleW( handle, &c, 1, &n, NULL );
    if (!ok or !n) return traits::eof();
    if (c == '\r') return underflow();

    n = WideCharToMultiByte( CP_UTF8, 0, (const wchar_t*)&c, 1, (char*)buffer, sizeof( buffer ), NULL, NULL );
    setg( buffer, buffer, buffer + n );

    return n ? traits::to_int_type( *buffer ) : traits::eof();
  }
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Output: public std::streambuf
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  using int_type = std::streambuf::int_type;
  using traits   = std::streambuf::traits_type;

  HANDLE      handle;
  std::string buffer;

  Output( HANDLE handle ): handle(handle) { }
  Output( const Output& that ): handle(that.handle) { }

  virtual int_type sync() override
  {
    DWORD n;
    std::wstring s( buffer.size(), 0 );
    s.resize( MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8, 0, (char*)buffer.c_str(), (int)buffer.size(), (wchar_t*)s.c_str(), (int)s.size() ) );
    if (buffer.size() and s.empty()) return -1;
    buffer.clear();
    return WriteConsoleW( handle, (wchar_t*)s.c_str(), (DWORD)s.size(), &n, NULL ) ? 0 : -1;
  }

  virtual int_type overflow( int_type value ) override
  {
    buffer.push_back( traits::to_char_type( value ) );
    if (traits::to_char_type( value ) == '\n') sync();
    return value;
  }
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void initialize()
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  // Update the standard I/O streams, maybe
  DWORD mode; HANDLE
  handle = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE  ); if (GetConsoleMode( handle, &mode )) std::cin .rdbuf( new Input ( handle ) );
  handle = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ); if (GetConsoleMode( handle, &mode )) std::cout.rdbuf( new Output( handle ) );
  handle = GetStdHandle( STD_ERROR_HANDLE  ); if (GetConsoleMode( handle, &mode )) std::cerr.rdbuf( new Output( handle ) );
}

} // namespace duthomhas::utf8::console

Now in your main(), make sure to initialize:
int main(...)
{
  duthomhas::utf8::console::initialize();

  // Ask the user to "Enter some Greek"
  std::cout << "Βάλε λίγα ελληνικά: ";
  std::string s;
  getline( std::cin, s );
  std::cout << "Good job! You entered: " << s << "!\n";

Again, this always works — because it bypasses the usual char-is-a-byte handling and uses Windows’ UTF-16 handling directly under the hood — but only if you are actually attached to the console!
⟶ Do remember, though, that the Windows console cannot handle anything outside the BMP. Redirected file I/O still works with the full Unicode set.
Unicode code point ≠ one character ≠ one byte
A full Unicode code point is 21 bits, and is typically stored in a 32-bit integer object (such as a char32_t).
If you wish to handle UTF-8 you can no longer treat “characters” as byte values. A single character can properly be one to four bytes long, and every successive character may be a different number of bytes.
That, and a single “character glyph” may be composed of more than one code point!
tl;dr: everything is a string.
Almost everything you will want to do with UTF-8 can be handled as substrings, and you should structure your code as such.
If you plan to do anything with the UTF-8 data, you should take a look at ICU.
Here is another answer I wrote specifically about using ICU.
⟶ ICU also includes functions for interacting with the console, but they are not out-of-the-box-supported on Windows — again due to compiler/version/etc.

Thank you so much for your answer, it works great out of the box. Luckily I don't need to do much with these strings other than displaying. Would it be possible to roughly explain what your solution overrides?

Also is there any way to have a similar implementation to parse characters using _getch()? I realize it only returns the ASCII byte of a character but after some testing I noticed that when entering a greek characters, 2 bytes are buffered, so you could use 2 _getch() to get a single character, though I guess there's no way of knowing how long each character is.

The input and output stream buffers are overridden to use the Win32 Console Wide I/O functions instead of the default I/O methods (whatever they are). Things like _getch() are designed to get a single key press, which is an entirely different beast than a “character”.

The good news is that keyboard input tends to come in chunks, so if a users inputs a character, you could certainly check to see if any input is available and read all input at once, and it will represent a single “character”. But again, that only works when you are attached to the keyboard. It might be worth asking a new question specifically about that. (Dunno if I’ll be able to give you a useful answer at this time, though.)

I see, but I'm assuming these chunks aren't delimited by anything other than their timing correct? Since _getch() and all other input methods I know of are blocking, I'm not sure how I could check if input is available. I'll consider asking a new question later if I need to. Thanks anyway!

The timing corresponds to the speed at which a human can reposition a finger to depress another key. The computer operates so much faster than that.

Pedantic: technically may be true that Unicode Codepoint != character, but Unicode explicit tell us that in Unicode standard both concept may be used interchangeably (the context should make obvious if there is a non-character). So like Unicode: let's remove such distinction which makes thing unnecessary difficult.

@GiacomoCatenazzi • in this particular context, they cannot be used interchangeably — the distinction is important (in this context).

@Eljay: I really do not see any relevance here. (maybe because later in the answer a new concept character glyph is introduced, which it is not character (use glyph or grapheme), and no... such concept doesn't exist (and depend on font, so also not relevant to the question). The distinction is really minor.

@GiacomoCatenazzi The relevance is that the traditional concept of a self-contained “character” doesn’t work in international text, nor in Unicode. You’ll notice that in my answer I do use the word interchangeably with “code point”. Continuing, a glyph is not a grapheme, and it does no good to confuse the two terms for the OP.

Because we are discussing c++ (char), now things get more confused. In Unicode, if we have a valid Unicode string, every code point (in the file) is a character, and every character is a codepoint), so much like char/w_char, just that a codepoint in the Unicode character database is also a character (the other: unassigned, never to be assigned, reserved, surrogates). -- I have no idea of "self contained character". Early ASCII allowed/standardized composed symbols (using DEL, so 3 characters: early ASCII time, nothing new under the bridge (or underline text). Maybe you can add some defs
